# Multitouch Pinch, Pan, Zoom in HTML 5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mobile-safari

I have most of a module written to handle multitouch pinch, pan and zoom on an HTML 5 canvas element. I will share it below. I've been developing in JavaScript for some time now, and this one continues to boggle me. If anybody has any insights, I will post the final version up on stack for everybody to share once it is confirmed working on my iPad.

Here is what I am doing:

`touchmove` events trigger the changing of variables. I use these variables to change the way in which my image is painted onto the canvas. I have eight variables, each corresponding to the options that can be put into the `drawImage()` function. These eight variables get updated through functions that increment/decrement their values and keep them within a certain range. The variables are closure variables, so they are global throughout my module.  To prevent over-processing, I make a call to this `drawImage()` function once every 40ms while the user has their finger pressed to the screen using a `setInterval()`.
Here is the problem:

`touchmove` events seem to be causing a race condition where my variables get updated by many different instances of that same event. I can somewhat confirm this through my console output, that tracks one variable that is bounded to never reach below 20. When I swipe in one direction quickly, that variable dips down far below 20. Then when I release my finger, swipe slowly, it returns to 20. Another thing that points me in this direction, when I look at these variables while stepping through my program, they differ from what my `console.log()` pumps out.

Note: The code successfully draws the image the first time, but not anytime thereafter. A basic rendition of my code is below... The full version is on [GitHub](https://github.com/ssweriduk/PinchPanZoom) inside the Scripts folder. It is a Sencha Touch v1.1 app at heart

```
function PinchPanZoomFile(config)
{
    /*
     * Closure variable declaration here...
     * Canvas Declaration here...
    */
    
    function handleTouchStart(e) {
        whatDown.oneDown = (e.originalEvent.targetTouches.length == 1) ? true : false;
        whatDown.twoDown = (e.originalEvent.targetTouches.length >= 2) ? true : false;
        
        drawInterval = setInterval(draw, 100);
    }
    
    function handleTouchEnd(e) {
        whatDown.oneDown = (e.originalEvent.targetTouches.length == 1) ? true : false;
        whatDown.twoDown = (e.originalEvent.targetTouches.length >= 2) ? true : false;
        clearInterval(drawInterval);
    }
    
    function handleTouchMove(e) {
        if(whatDown.twoDown) {
            /*
             * Do Panning & Zooming
            */  
            changeWindowXBy(deltaDistance); //deltaDistance
            changeWindowYBy(deltaDistance); //deltaDistance
            changeCanvasXBy(deltaX); //Pan
            changeCanvasYBy(deltaY); //Pan
            changeWindowDimsBy(deltaDistance*-1,deltaDistance*-1); //(deltaDistance)*-1 -- get smaller when zooming in.
            changeCanvasWindowDimsBy(deltaDistance,deltaDistance); //deltaDistance -- get bigger when zooming in
            
        } else if(whatDown.oneDown) {
            /*
             * Do Panning
            */
            changeWindowXBy(0);
            changeWindowYBy(0);
            changeCanvasXBy(deltaX);
            changeCanvasYBy(deltaY);
            changeWindowDimsBy(0,0);
            changeCanvasWindowDimsBy(0,0);
        }
    }
    
    function draw() {
        //Draw Image Off Screen
        var offScreenCtx = offScreenCanvas[0].getContext('2d');
        offScreenCtx.save();
        offScreenCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        offScreenCtx.restore();
        offScreenCtx.drawImage(base64Image, 
            parseInt(windowX), 
            parseInt(windowY), 
            parseInt(windowWidth), 
            parseInt(windowHeight), 
            parseInt(canvasX), 
            parseInt(canvasY), 
            parseInt(canvasWindowWidth), 
            parseInt(canvasWindowHeight)
        );
        
        //Draw Image On Screen
        var offScreenImageData = offScreenCtx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        var onScreenCtx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
        onScreenCtx.putImageData(offScreenImageData, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: **UPDATE:** I have published the latest version on [GitHub](https://github.com/ssweriduk/PinchPanZoom/blob/Add-DataStore-to-store-and-set-data/Scripts/PinchPanZoom.js). I ended up taking the variables out of the main scope, and throwing them into their own container. Worked great. Still working on Panning and Zooming though... Will update with progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend using Sencha Touch 2.0.1, as it supports a lot of the touch events you need. See http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/touchevents for examples.

Comment: Yeah I actually ended up scrapping the above code and using ST. Far less jumpy. Also scrapped the canvas method and went straight for an <img> tag...